# javascript toggle class off when other element is selected

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 divs that are left and right of each other. On the left is a list of `<li>` items with `<a>` on the inside.

On the right is a series of `<div>`'s with `display: none;` as their initial class. I wrote a function to make these `<div>`'s appear as their corresponding `<li>` items are selected on the left. The HTML for the list on the left is:

```
<ul class="nav flex-column">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="toggle_visibility('item1');" href="javascript:void(0)">Item 1</a>
    </li> 
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" onclick="toggle_visibility('item2');" href="javascript:void(0)">Item 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the HTML for the list on the right is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="item1">
        <h2 class="text-center">Item 1</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="item2">
        <h2 class="text-center">Item 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

My javascript function is:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    if(e.style.display == 'block')
        e.style.display = 'none';
    else
        e.style.display = 'block';
}
```

What happens is they toggle on and off just fine, but they stack on top of each other when clicked. What I want them to do is have the `<div>` that is selected take the place of whatever is displayed, and not have them displayed on top of each other.

This is just a sample, I have about 8 of these links that I need to select and have a div appear as needed.

I am very new to javascript, I have written while loops before and assume I will need to do that and loop through all of these as an array. But what am I checking for and how do I make the one item remove the display when the other one is selected?

I am also completely open to the possibility that I am making this more complicated than what it should be.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all; I highly recommend keep digging with JavaScript, don't get disappointed, ask others, learn more about it and NEVER stop learning!

I've come up with a solution, that allows you to show/hide divs as you wanted. Addition to that, it is 100% dynamically and you can add as many links/divs as you want without extra efforts!

Here is a [Live Preview Pen](https://codepen.io/elharony/pen/MVRewy).
*I used the bootstrap grid to enhance the UI a little bit*

Anyways, here is the code without extras:

**HTML**

```
<!-- Toggle Links -->
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggle">Item #1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggle">Item #2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="toggle">Item #3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<!-- Show/Hide Divs -->
<div>
  <div class="item">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item">Item 3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
  display: none;
}
```

**Vanilla JS**

```
// Select All Links
const toggleLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".toggle");

// Select All divs
const allDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".item");

// Add a `click` event to each link
for(let i = 0; i < toggleLinks.length; i++) {
  toggleLinks[i].addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // To avoid reloading the page

    // Make sure that ALL divs are hidden
    for(let x = 0; x < allDivs.length; x++) {
      allDivs[x].style.display = "none"
    }

    // Show only ONE div based on the triggered link's index
    const displayDiv = allDivs[i];
    // You can display the div directly without `displayDiv` variable, but it is made for better readability only!
    displayDiv.style.display = "block";
    // Like this: allDivs[i].style.display = "block"

  });
}
```

The actual code is VERY short, but I tried to explain it with as many comments as I could.

I hope you find it easy-to-read and start implementing this into your project!

*Feel free to ask any further questions about the code above, if you got any!*

Comment: This was fantastic, thank you for such a highly organized answer. One question: how does the link know which div to display when you click on it? Like how does clicking on div 2 to only trigger div 2 to show?

Comment: Good question! Simply, by its index. I loop over all `links` then `addEventListener` to each link `toggleLinks[i]`, then I used that `i` index to `display` the desired div! . So, `const displayDiv = allDivs[i];` the `i` refers to the same index as the triggered `link`. Got it now? If not, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery

`$("div:not(#id)").css("display", "none");
$("#id").css("display", "block");`

or

You are using pure JS

`document.querySelector("div:not(#id).style.display = none")
document.getElementById(#id).style.display = block`